# Laravel - Composer install does not create "autoload.php" file in vendor directory

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a problem setting up an existing project on my local environment.

The `composer install` command is running smoothly BUT no `autoload.php` file is created.

`composer update` didn't solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try running `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Here the result of `composer-autoload`:
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'LaravelQRCode\Providers\QRCodeServiceProvider' not found

Comment: For additional information, when I run `composer install`, I get an error about a repo in my project that is not available anymore. Is it related ? @ChrisWhite

Comment: That's probably it. Unfortunately I don't know anything about Laravel, but perhaps someone will come along that does. :)

Comment: Of interest, github 404s on the LaravelQRCode project :(

Comment: Yup I saw that ^^ I just got the Provider out and everything worked well ! Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Excellent! Good luck! :)